# How to implement repository in Spring data JPA when MappedSuperClass is involved?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, mappedsuperclass

I'm implementing the repository structure of an entity which extends a MappedSuperClass in Sping data JPA.

Base.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base {
    public abstract Long getId();
    public abstract void setId(Long id);
    public abstract String getFirstName();
    public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

BaseImpl.java:

```
@Entity
public class BaseImpl extends Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;

    ...
//Default and parameterised constructors
//Getters and setters
//Equals and hashcode
//toString
}
```

BaseRepository.java:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends Base, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

BaseRepositoryImpl.java:

```
public interface BaseRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepository<BaseImpl, Long> {

}
```

When I try to save Base object in the following way:

```
@Autowired
BaseRepositoryImpl baseRepositoryImpl;

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
    Base base = new BaseImpl();
    base.setFirstName("Mamatha");

    System.out.println(baseRepositoryImpl.save(base));
}
```

I do see a compile time error in the sysout line saying `"The method save(Iterable<S>) in the type JpaRepository<BaseImpl,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Base)"`. 
In JPA, everything happens through MappedSuperClass only, except the instantiation. Am I going wrong in implementing the repository structure. Please help.

Comment: You are persisting an entity which is of type `BaseImpl` using a repository which takes `BaseDataImpl` as entities!! Please also post your `BaseDataImpl` Entity.

Comment: The provided code doesn't compile so there is no question of a runtime error. `BaseRepositoryImpl.save` expects a `BaseImpl` whereas it is being passed a `Base` instance.

Comment: @manish: Yes, it is a compile time error only. Not the runtime one. Have updated the question.

Comment: @AbdullahWasi: Actually, BaseDataImpl was a mistake, It should have been BaseImpl only. Have updated the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why you are getting a compile-time error (there is a type mismatch), how to fix it (pass the correct type to the `save` method) or something else?

Comment: @manish: I would want everything using Base only, the way we do it in JPA. I cannot use the BaseRepository object to save, because it will be a no repository bean class.

Comment: You can have `BaseImpl something = new BaseImpl(); something.setFirstName(...); Base base = baseRepositoryImpl.save(something);`. You can then use the `Base` instance returned by the `save` method instead of passing a `Base` instance to it, which is not possible due to type-safety.

Comment: Well, that means I can't send a mappedSuperClass object at all to the save function. In JPA, we can send a mappedSuperClass object  to save/persist function. Yes, what returns is a MappedSuperClass object.

Comment: " In JPA, we can send a mappedSuperClass object to save/persist function." Really? I think you're mistaken. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Cannot_query.2C_persist.2C_or_have_relationships